# YouTube Api v3 returns 500 internal server error when making POST request on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, youtube-data-api

I have weird problem with YouTube Api V3.
My app is on AngularJS and it works perfectly. The only one problem is when I try to subscribe for a channel, I receive 500 Internal Server Error. The interesting thing is that I receive this error only on iOS. When I use the app on Android I receive 200 OK and the user is subscribed for the channel. When I try through Postman it also works as it is expected but I can't understand what's the problem with iOS.

Аny ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried printing the request and comparing it with Postman's ? Have a look at Charles (iOS app version included). Include your code if you can since it'll be impossible to debug the issue otherwise

Comment: Thanks, nathan. 

After a lot of investigation, the problem was isolated and the cause was that there were some missing permissions in iOS token generator.